# Use Tab with new ToolBar (AppCompat v7-21)

Tags: android, tabs, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I was using SupportActionBar with tabs and a custom ActionBar theme (created with http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), that show the tabs only when the user expands the search view.

```
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I migrated from ActionBar to Toolbar. My app really needs to support API 9.

Is there a way to use this code to add the tabs back?:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.new_actionbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

If possible, how can I use my custom theme or style the toolbar?

The documentation says that this is deprecated and suggests using a different type of navigation.
But I don't know of any other components in Android that have the same functionality.

Some help?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

With the API 21 the method `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setNavigationMode(int)).

**UPDATE 01/08/2019 (Material Components Library)**

Add the dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies { implementation ‘com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0’ }
```

Then you can use the new [`TabLayout`](https://material.io/develop/android/components/tab-layout/).

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

     <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout   ...>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar  .../>


        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
         ...
         />

     </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

     <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager 
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The code is simple:

```
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```

---

**UPDATE 29/05/2015 (Support Library)**

With the new **Design Support Library** now you can use the  [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).

Just add this dependency to your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

The code is very simple:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

To implement many of the features of material designs you should use it within a 
[CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) and a [AppBarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html).

Something like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">


     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

**OLD**

You can use a different pattern. For example you can use the same example that you can see in googleio14.

It uses a `SlidingTabLayout` which works with a `ViewPager`.

[Here you can find the example](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) (it is in your sdk example)

Here you can find the Google io14 example:

- [Layout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/activity_my_schedule_narrow.xml)
- [Java](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java)

Comment: what to do if I don't require the ViewPager and want the Tabs?

Comment: @noundla You can probably use RadioGroup+RadioButtons, and style them so they will look as tabs

Comment: I have the same idea if I don't find anything. I am searching for the Toolbar Tabs if there is anything like Actionbar with Tabs. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: So to implement tabs ([looking like this](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html)) with Toolbar, is the best pratice *really* to copy-paste the io14 example code and work from there? That looks like much more work than what [adding tabs to Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs) was.

Comment: @noundla what did you end up doing to solve this? I also need material style tabs and not the viewpager integration

Comment: @GregEnnis I used TabWidget to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Google is now working with its 'support-design' library, which includes 'TabLayout'. Stay tuned for an update. (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java)

Comment: @TaehoKim this code is not yet available in support libraries released

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yup right. That's why I commented 'Stay tuned'... :) While it is not released, but you can check out the code from the link in the above.

Comment: Will it really be a new 'support-design' library or did you mean an update from the current 'support-library'?

Comment: Tabs has been an issue for Android since forever, they keep reinventing it, It's gotten to the point where I'm more used to custom implementations than any of the Google Ways of doing it *shrugs*

Comment: I have two tabs, they looks good on mobile but on Nexus 7 it does not fill the all width. I want it like we have in hangout 
http://www.evernote.com/shard/s526/sh/6662a207-e518-45bc-b0a7-0cb102dfe3a0/1c1a13dfd8e68e4f20f8b95e63054c69

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can u pls tell me i was using getActionBar now i have integrated tablayout +viewpager in one of my fragments now i changed mya actionBar to getSupportActionBar ---> but now its not taking full width of device i m using custom xml for actionbar there is no padding , margin etc

Comment: @erum you should open a new question in SO.

Comment: can't believe there are so many ways of doing something that should be done in a few steps.. sick of the hello "component" goodbye "old-component" stuff.. that, of course, are not backwards compatible

Answer (score 14):

Although probably a little late to answer this question now, I realised that I wrote [an answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868277/using-sliding-tabs-with-toolbar/29991826#29991826) which covers both using the Design Support Library and prior to Google I/O.

I have included the essential parts below:

---

Using a `TabLayout` with the `Toolbar` has become much simpler since the announcement of the *Android Design Support Library* meaning we no longer need to download custom view classes.

From the [Android Developers' Blogspot post on the Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html):

> **Tabs**:
>
> Switching between different views in your app via [tabs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html) is not a new concept to material design and they are equally at home as a [top level navigation pattern](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/app-structure.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog#app-structure-top-level-navigation-strategies) or for organizing different groupings of content within your app (say, different genres of music).
>
> [image]
>
> The Design library’s [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) implements both fixed tabs, where the view’s width is divided equally between all of the tabs, as well as scrollable tabs, where the tabs are not a uniform size and can scroll horizontally. Tabs can be added programmatically:
>
> `TabLayout tabLayout = ...;`
> `tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));`
>
> However, if you are using a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) for horizontal paging between tabs, you can create tabs directly from your [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog)’s [getPageTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog#getPageTitle(int)) and then connect the two together using `setupWithViewPager()`. This ensures that tab selection events update the ViewPager and page changes update the selected tab.

---

If you are not using the Design Support library, you will instead need to do the following:

**1.** Download the [`SlidingTabLayout.java`](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) and [`SlidingTabStrip.java`](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java) files from Google's I/O Conference app on GitHub. These would be the views that would be used in the tab layout, so I created a folder with my other Java activities called 'view' and placed them there.

**2.** Edit your layout to include the `SlidingTabLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ... >

    <!-- This is the Toolbar with the tabs underneath -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ... >

        <include android:id="@+id/my_toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <com.mycompany.myapp.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This is the ViewPager (which you already should have if you have
        used tabs before) -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

*The line which references the `Toolbar` (`<include android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />`), is referencing another XML file I had used to make the `Toolbar`.*

**3.** Change the package names in `SlidingTabLayout.java` and `SlidingTabStrip.java` corresponding to where they were placed. In my case, I used something similar to: `package com.mycompany.myapp.view;` for both of these files. Organise imports and add in any necessary, as noted by the IDE you are using.

**4.** In your `Activity` (which was extending `AppCompatActivity`), setup the `Toolbar` in the `onCreate` method:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**5.** Setup the `ViewPager` and `SlidingTabLayout` parts:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_line));   
mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

*The colour '`tab_line`' was a colour I had declared in `color.xml` which would be the colour of the tab line indicator. Also note that the variables above were global which I defined previously in this activity:*

```
SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
ViewPager mViewPager;
```

**6.** Finally, setup the `ViewPagerAdapter` which I had called earlier. This would be responsible for changing the page depending on which tab was selected. I used the following code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Returns the number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // Returns a new instance of the fragment
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentOne();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTwo();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentThree();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

As I mentioned above, further details to these solutions are available on [another question I answered, about using Sliding Tabs with the Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868277/using-sliding-tabs-with-toolbar/29991826#29991826).

Comment: Please don't post link only answers referencing your own post. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: I liked this answer! helped me too. for anyone need the toolbar xml file click his last link in the answer or this. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar#reusing-the-toolbar