# Adding Sliding Tabs using Support Library v7:21 with Toolbar in Android Developer Tools for existing project

Tags: android-tabs, android-5.0-lollipop, eclipse-adt, android-toolbar

I have already read the information in this link: [Use Tab with new ToolBar (AppCompat v7-21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21) and did a lot of research on the same.

But the problem is the SlidingTabLayout project is using Gradle build files and structure. I want to add the tab layout using eclipse. How do I do this?

I did run the SlidingTabLayout project in Android Studio though. But how do I add Tabs to Toolbar in v7:21?

Note:
All this needs to be done in a existing project, which has everything setup and warns me of the deprecated APIs like ActionBar.setNavigationMode, etc. in API 21

Answer (score 15):

1 . Copy SlidingTabLayout.java from https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html and paste it in your package.

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.mysliding;

import com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout;
import com.example.mysliding.SlidingTabsBasicFragment.SamplePagerAdapter;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

static final String LOG_TAG = "SlidingTabsBasicFragment";
private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sample);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    /*
     * FragmentTransaction transaction =
     * getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     * SlidingTabsBasicFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsBasicFragment();
     * transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
     * transaction.commit();
     */

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    /**
     * @return the number of pages to display
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the value returned from
     *         {@link #instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)} is the same object
     *         as the {@link View} added to the {@link ViewPager}.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o == view;
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (pageradapter_getpagetitle)
    /**
     * Return the title of the item at {@code position}. This is important
     * as what this method returns is what is displayed in the
     * {@link SlidingTabLayout}.
     * <p>
     * Here we construct one using the position value, but for real
     * application the title should refer to the item's contents.
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Item " + (position + 1);
    }

    // END_INCLUDE (pageradapter_getpagetitle)

    /**
     * Instantiate the {@link View} which should be displayed at
     * {@code position}. Here we inflate a layout from the apps resources
     * and then change the text view to signify the position.
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // Inflate a new layout from our resources

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                container, false);
        // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
        container.addView(view);

        // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "instantiateItem() [position: " + position + "]");

        // Return the View
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy the item from the {@link ViewPager}. In our case this is
     * simply removing the {@link View}.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroyItem() [position: " + position + "]");
    }

}
```

}

fragment_sample.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Pager_item.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:text="Page:"/>

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/item_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="80sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The above works for me to add tabs to toolbar.Is it working in your case.

Comment: i m getting an error of 11-21 12:34:15.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17172): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.toolbartabdemo.view.SlidingTabLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.toolbartabdemo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Comment: i get it working by checking v5 in the order and export tab and thank u so much for sharing the code it is working perfectly and saved my lot of time.

Comment: Hii Amit does the above code gives the answer to your question?

Comment: Thanks @kunal.c, this looks great! But if I am putting this into a `Fragment`, instead of an `Activity`, would I use that `FragmentTransaction` code that was commented out? Also, my `getLayoutInflater()` in the `instantiateItem()` method is red... how would that be fixed? Thx if you know!

Comment: Actually the 2nd question of mine is fixed. When using fragments, I must put `getActivity().getLayoutInflator()...` But I noticed another problem. The `ToolBar` in `onCreate()` is instantiating the toolbar xml, but the variable `toolbar` is never used. Was that intentional or should it be used for something?

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem. Since that Android is changing the usage of ActionBar and Tabs again and again it is really hard to know what is the most appropriate implementation of it.

So I followed the sample [that is shown here](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) but I added some additional functionalities. You can see my version and its' usage [on this gist](https://gist.github.com/eluleci/199be9a0d1af42653b5b).

What I added are;

- Enabling giving tabs equal width (if there are two tabs they'll have half width of actionbar)
- Showing image instead of text or showing both (with your custom view) text and image at tabs

## UPDATE

There is a new layout called [Tab Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) within the support library. You can use it instead.

Also you can see another response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020) tells more about it.

Comment: I implemented that solution, but it's far from material design [tabs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html). I'm still looking for the solution :/

Comment: actually it is up to you to style the tabs. I changed the constants in SlidingTabStrip class and added exactly same colors to activity_main.xml. You can check the [gist](https://gist.github.com/eluleci/199be9a0d1af42653b5b) again. So now it looks exactly same as the material tabs in the link you gave. TIP: Use appcompat 7 with dark theme in your app.

Comment: IMPORTANT: this answer is now deprecated, here is the correct one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020

Answer (score 0):

Just add ViewPager and SlidingTabLayout to your xml:

```xml
    <com.example.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your Code create an Adapter for your ViewPager (as example FragmentPagerAdapter) and bind them to your ViewPager, after bind the SlidingTabLayout to your ViewPager:

```java
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

final SlidingTabLayout tabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
tabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found this library that seemes to be pretty much what is mentioned here already, but with less manual lifting. Have a look at https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs.

To shamelessly plug my self, this is a sample of it in action https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snilius.fhstats.

The only thing missing from it at the point of writing this is having the tab indicator sliding between tabs when paging the viewpager, like is does on Google Play.