# How to implement sliding tab navigation with multiple fragments

Tags: android, material-design, pagerslidingtabstrip

I want to add some proper navigation to my app. I have two fragments and I want to make a title strip [tabs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage) (similar to the one in Play Newsstand or the Play Store with material design) that switches between the two fragments. I don't have a very good understanding of the `ViewPager` or `PagerAdapter`. I'm also trying to use [this library](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip). I don't know where to get started. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet... I don't know where to get started.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually did something myself for once. Okay.

First, add the library to your dependencies in the **build.gradle** file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'
}
```

This is what my **activity_main.xml** looks like. I added the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` (with my own customization, see the [Github repo](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip) for more) and my `ViewPager` from the support library.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#33B5E5"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:pstsPaddingMiddle="true" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Next, I did the following steps in the `onCreate()` method of my **MainActivity.java**:

```
    // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

And finally, the `FragmentPagerAdapter` class, also in **MainActivity.java**. Notice the `Fragment getItem()` method; this is where I switched between my fragments using the position of the tabs.

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final String[] TITLES = {"Regular Tenses", "Perfect Tenses"};

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return TITLES[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return TITLES.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new MainFragment();
        case 1:
            return new PerfectFragment();
    }

    return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Acutally I am new in using paging tab strip, I have been using toolbar for material design. Is the library `PagerSlidingTabStrip` working for you using toolbar.?

Comment: @Dory the library works perfectly with the Toolbar from the support library.

Comment: can I implement all this in a fragment?

Comment: @Mike I don't see why not!

Answer (score 0):

If your app has an ActionBar, you can use `setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) there is a snippet code example and explanation, under *Adding Navigation Tabs* subtitle.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs) for swipeable tabs with ActionBar.

Comment: With the API 21 the method setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) is deprecated.

Comment: thks, do you know what is the suggested alternative?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020

Comment: Finally tried it, I really do not like too much: too many elements that move simultaneously, in my opinion.

Comment: And the selected title often remains confined to the edges of the layout.