# AppCompat, trying to style tabbar in version 7.21

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appcompat

I am trying to style the TabBar using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/palette_1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/palette_5</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/palette_1</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>

        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarTabBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarTabBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@color/palette_5</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@color/palette_5</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/palette_5</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarTabBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@color/palette_5</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.NoTitleBar" parent="MyTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Whewre palette_1 is green and palette_5 is blue for example.
The actionBar is blue but the tabbar stays the color that i define in android:windowBackground, which is green.

This is the code i came up with after searching numerous topics. But yet it seems to be conflicting somewhere.

Comment: Action bar navigation modes **are deprecated** and **not supported by inline toolbar** action bars. 

You should consider using different pattern:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020