# How to implement getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST); in Lollipop

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop, android-spinner, android-toolbar

I want to implement such a functionality :

[image]

So - Navigation Drawer and Drop Down list for the Lollipop. 
As I've read - we could implement this feature with the

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

in the earlier versions. 
But now, this method is deprecated for the Lolipop. 
I found this way :

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_parent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
  >


    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="mobapply.freightexchange.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

where `toolbar` layout looks like :

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

But the layouts places one after the another - so `Toolbar` is not included in the `Navigation Drawer`.

Do somebody had experience implementing this in the Lollipop ?

Comment: You need to use sliding tab layout. Refer this http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

Comment: Sliding Tab Layout is about the tabs not about the Drop Down, I guess.

Comment: can you post a screenshot? try setting toolbar width to match parent

Comment: what screenshot do you mean ? I've posted the screen shot of those, what I want. That is Drop Down list ability near the Navigation Drawer menu icon in the left top corner of the screen.

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020