# Using Sliding Tabs with Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tabs, android-toolbar

I've started to change from using `ActionBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity`, but I've also started using the `Toolbar` as well instead of a standard `ActionBar`.

However, in one of my activities which has a swiping tab type of layout, the following line seems to be deprecated:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Although I have looked at some other answers on Stack Overflow regarding this, is there any built-in way of changing this to support using the `Toolbar`. If so, could you explain exactly how I would go about changing it? How would deprecated methods like `onTabSelected` be changed?

Also, I've noticed that the Google Play Music app has what looks like an extended toolbar/section underneath the tabs (see [this image for what I am talking about](http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/MaterialDesignMusicPlayer-Play-Music.jpg?6055c3)). How would I be able to have that type of layout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for sliding tab use https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html

Comment: I've had a look at the code, but I'm not sure exactly how it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020

Comment: As I said, I've had a look at the code, but there are a lot of Java files and layout files. How exactly does it work?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I managed to add in the code from the SlidingTabsBasic sample, but this does not give me the layout I want. I've added it in, and the tabs are separate from the toolbar, and are grey, with a thick borderline. I want a layout something more like [this](http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/MaterialDesignMusicPlayer-Play-Music.jpg?6055c3) (on the left side). As you can see, in that image, the tabs are connected to the toolbar and look part of it. I also like the orange extended part that drops below the tabs but I wouldn't mind not having that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So after a few days of lots of research, and looking through GitHub, I finally managed to solve my problem.

## Steps to updating the ActionBar tabs to Toolbar tabs using AppCompatActivity:

---

### UPDATE: After Friday 29th May 2015:

Thankfully, using a `TabLayout` with the `Toolbar` has become much simpler since the announcement of the *Android Design Support Library* in Google I/O 2015.
We no longer need to download custom view classes, and this is something Google really should have done a long time ago.

From the [Android Developers' Blogspot post on the Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html):

> **Tabs**:
>
> Switching between different views in your app via [tabs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html) is not a new concept to material design and they are equally at home as a [top level navigation pattern](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/app-structure.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog#app-structure-top-level-navigation-strategies) or for organizing different groupings of content within your app (say, different genres of music).
>
> [image]
>
> The Design library’s [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) implements both fixed tabs, where the view’s width is divided equally between all of the tabs, as well as scrollable tabs, where the tabs are not a uniform size and can scroll horizontally. Tabs can be added programmatically:
>
> `TabLayout tabLayout = ...;`
> `tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));`
>
> However, if you are using a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) for horizontal paging between tabs, you can create tabs directly from your [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog)’s [getPageTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog#getPageTitle(int)) and then connect the two together using `setupWithViewPager()`. This ensures that tab selection events update the ViewPager and page changes update the selected tab.

---

### Prior to Google I/O 2015:

Firstly, I downloaded the [`SlidingTabLayout.java`](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) and [`SlidingTabStrip.java`](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java) files from Google's I/O Conference app on GitHub. These would be the views that would be used in the tab layout, so I created a folder with my other Java activities called 'view' and placed them there.

Next, I edited my activity layout `.xml` to look a bit like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.MyActivity" >

    <!-- This is the Toolbar with the tabs underneath -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/detail_headerBar"
        style="@style/HeaderBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <com.mycompany.myapp.view.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This is the ViewPager (which I had used before) and 
         it would be responsible for the swiping to change layouts -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/detail_headerBar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/detail_adView" />

    <!-- I also had an AdView in my layout,
         but this is not necessary for creating tab layouts -->
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/detail_adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The line which references the `Toolbar` (`<include android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />`), is referencing the following layout (for those who aren't sure how to use the `Toolbar` yet):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And in both of the `.xml` layout files above, `?attr/colorPrimary`, refers to the primary colour of my app (which I had defined in a style).

Also, in the first layout, the style I had mentioned as `@style/HeaderBar` refers to the following:

```
<style name="HeaderBar">
    <item name="android:background">?colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
    <!-- You may have to override this in a v21 version of this file -->
</style>
```

Before I started setting up the layouts in Java, I had to make sure to change the package names in `SlidingTabLayout.java` and `SlidingTabStrip.java` corresponding to where they were placed. In my case, I used: `package com.mycompany.myapp.view;` in both of these files.

Now, in my `Activity` (which was extending `AppCompatActivity`), I first added the following in the `onCreate` method:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

This would be reponsible for displaying the `Toolbar`.

Then I setup the `ViewPager` and `SlidingTabLayout` parts:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_line));   
mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

The colour '`tab_line`' was a colour I had declared in `color.xml` which would be the colour of the tab line indicator. Also note that the variables above were global which I defined previously in this activity:

```
SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
ViewPager mViewPager;
```

The final thing to do was to setup the `ViewPagerAdapter` which I had called eariler. This would be responsible for changing the page depending on which tab was selected. I used the following:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Returns the number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // Returns a new instance of the fragment
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentOne();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTwo();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentThree();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope this was a thorough enough answer for those who are having the same trouble as I did, when switching from `ActionBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity` and starting to use `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar`. If there is anything that is unclear, feel free to comment below.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works great for the most part. The only issue I'm running into is that I don't see any actual tabs at the top of my screen. I can scroll left and right to different viewpages, just no tabs to designate what I'm looking at. Any ideas? (I followed the code example you provided very closely)

Comment: @TheRedAgent Hmm. Have you included the `SlidingTabLayout` in the activity layout?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh: Thanks for your answer. Helps alot. But now i want to change the text of tabs at run time. How to do that?

Comment: @ManojFegde If you are using a `ViewPager` with an adapter, specify names in the `getPageTitle` method, as described at the bottom of my answer. If you are not using a `ViewPager`, you should do `tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));`, changing 'Tab 1' depending on the name you want. Details to both of these solutions are given in my answer above.

Comment: I tried tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1")); but getting error as : The method newTab() is undefined for the type SlidingTabLayout

Comment: Just want to change text of tab at run time.

Comment: @ManojFegde If you are using a `SlidingTabLayout`, you should not use `tabLayout.addTab(...);` because they are different things. If you are using a `SlidingTabLayout`, you should use a `ViewPager`. The second half of my answer (entitled 'Prior to Google I/O 2015'), describes everything you would need to do to use a `SlidingTabLayout`.

Comment: Thanx. It works. Now one more thing that i want to change selected tab indicator color to custom from blue.

Comment: I think you should be able to do that using `mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources.getColor(R.color.your_colour));`, where 'your_colour' is your tab indicator colour, specified in your colours XML file.

Comment: page not found for SlidingTabLayout.java