# Android material tabs w/ appcompat

Tags: android, material-design, android-tabs

I want to setup a 'tabbed' application.  Looking through all the tutorials including the google docs here:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

However as I start to go through the docs I get all kinds of deprecated warnings:

```
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
```

I would really like to start off right and use any new non deprecated methods.  Most examples of tab applications are years old.  What am I missing?  Am I searching for the wrong thing?  Can someone point me in the right direction for developing a tabbed application.

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Don't see tabs in that example.

Comment: @lostintranslation look at the `MainActivity`

Comment: Far as I can tell that is setting up a Navigation Drawer, not tabs.  Am I missing something.

Comment: @lostintranslation if you look at the end of onCreate you see `TabLayout`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Action bar tabs were deprecated in Android 5.0, last fall.

> Can someone point me in the right direction for developing a tabbed application.

[Use `TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), though this is a very new addition to the Android Support libraries.

Or, use `ViewPager` with your favorite tabbed indicator, of which [there are many](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111).

Or, use `FragmentTabHost`.

Comment: TabLayout is indeed very new, documentation and examples leave a lot to be desired ;)  Messing w/ it now, thanks!

Comment: In case anyone else is looking this is perfect.  https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout