# What is an alternative way to implement tab on ActionBar when everything is deprecated?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, deprecated, android-navigation

today I'm trying to implement tab navigation on ActionBar. However, as you can see from the picture below, a lot of functions were deprecated.

[image: Deprecated functions]

So, what is the alternative way to implement tab navigation? Thanks for your help.

Comment: use android design library for this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

check this example http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/

Comment: You shouldn't be using ActionBar anymore, use the Toolbar instead

Comment: Check also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21/26543020#26543020