# Unable to locate getResources()

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Look for class MyPagerActivity and MyFragment**

> There is the error coming Unable to locate GetResources(), and MyFragment's static is not allowed. The code was earlier running perfectly well, and suddenly these errors started showing, when I added the Floating Action Button classes. I am very new in Android Programming. Kindly Help.

```
    package demo.demo2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton;
import demo.demo2.FloatingActionsMenu;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import tabs.SlidingTabLayout;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    Activity activity;

    private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment=(NavigationDrawerFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);


        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);

        findViewById(R.id.pink_icon).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Clicked pink Floating Action Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });






        FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.setter);
        button.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
        button.setColorNormalResId(R.color.pink);
        button.setColorPressedResId(R.color.pink_pressed);
        button.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fab_star);
        button.setStrokeVisible(false);

        final View actionB = findViewById(R.id.action_b);

        FloatingActionButton actionC = new FloatingActionButton(getBaseContext());
        actionC.setTitle("Hide/Show Action above");
        actionC.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                actionB.setVisibility(actionB.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });

        final FloatingActionsMenu menuMultipleActions = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions);
        menuMultipleActions.addButton(actionC);

        final FloatingActionButton removeAction = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.button_remove);
        removeAction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions_down)).removeButton(removeAction);
            }
        });

        ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        drawable.getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        ((FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.setter_drawable)).setIconDrawable(drawable);

        final FloatingActionButton actionA = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.action_a);
        actionA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                actionA.setTitle("Action A clicked");
            }
        });

        // Test that FAMs containing FABs with visibility GONE do not cause crashes
        findViewById(R.id.button_gone).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        final FloatingActionButton actionEnable = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.action_enable);
        actionEnable.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                menuMultipleActions.setEnabled(!menuMultipleActions.isEnabled());
            }
        });

        FloatingActionsMenu rightLabels = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.right_labels);
        FloatingActionButton addedOnce = new FloatingActionButton(this);
        addedOnce.setTitle("Added once");
        rightLabels.addButton(addedOnce);

        FloatingActionButton addedTwice = new FloatingActionButton(this);
        addedTwice.setTitle("Added twice");
        rightLabels.addButton(addedTwice);
        rightLabels.removeButton(addedTwice);
        rightLabels.addButton(addedTwice);
    }











    }


    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        String[] tabs;
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tabs =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            MyFragment myFragment=MyFragment.getInstance(position);
            return myFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 6;
        }
    }

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        private TextView textView;
        public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {

            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            Bundle args=new Bundle();
            args.putInt("position",position);
            myFragment.setArguments(args);
            return myFragment;

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my,container,false);
            textView=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.position);
            Bundle bundle=getArguments();
            if (bundle!=null)
            {
                textView.setText("The Page Selected is"  +bundle.getInt("position"));
            }
            return layout;
        }
    }
```

And this is the stack Trace

> Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources,
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. :clean UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:clean :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72311Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library
>   :app:prepareComGetbaseFloatingactionbutton1101Library
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
>   :app:mergeDebugResources :app:processDebugManifest
>   :app:processDebugResources :app:generateDebugSources
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Aprajeeta\Studies\android_work\Demo2\app\src\main\java\demo\demo2\Main3Activity.java:151:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               tabs =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
>                     ^   symbol:   method getResources()   location: class MyPagerAdapter Note: Some input files use or override a
>   deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 1
>   error
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 39.934 secs

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="demo.demo2.Main3Activity"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="demo.demo2.Main3Activity">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <tabs.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/pink_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_fab_star"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/pink"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/pink_pressed"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/pink_icon"
            android:text="Text below button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            style="@style/menu_labels_style"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"/>

        <demo.demo2.AddFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/semi_transparent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/pink_icon"
            fab:fab_plusIconColor="@color/white"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/blue_semi_transparent"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/blue_semi_transparent_pressed"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

        <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/setter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/semi_transparent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

        <demo.demo2.AddFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/normal_plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            fab:fab_plusIconColor="@color/half_black"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

        <demo.demo2.FloatingActionsMenu
            android:id="@+id/right_labels"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/normal_plus"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
            fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
            fab:fab_addButtonSize="mini"
            fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
            fab:fab_labelsPosition="right">

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="Label on the right"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_size="mini"
                fab:fab_title="Another one on the right"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

        </demo.demo2.FloatingActionsMenu>

        <demo.demo2.FloatingActionsMenu
            android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
            fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
            fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/action_a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="Action A"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/action_b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="Action with a very long name that won\'t fit on the screen"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

        </demo.demo2.FloatingActionsMenu>

        <demo.demo2.FloatingActionsMenu
            android:id="@+id/multiple_actions_down"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
            fab:fab_addButtonSize="mini"
            fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
            fab:fab_expandDirection="down"
            fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                fab:fab_size="mini"/>

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/button_remove"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                fab:fab_title="Click to remove"/>

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/button_gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/action_enable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="Set bottom menu enabled/disabled"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

        </demo.demo2.FloatingActionsMenu>

        <demo.demo2.FloatingActionsMenu
            android:id="@+id/multiple_actions_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/multiple_actions_down"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/multiple_actions_down"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
            fab:fab_addButtonSize="mini"
            fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
            fab:fab_addButtonStrokeVisible="false"
            fab:fab_expandDirection="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                fab:fab_size="mini"/>

            <demo.demo2.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                fab:fab_size="mini"/>

        </demo.demo2.FloatingActionsMenu>

        <demo.demo2.AddFloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/setter_drawable"
            android:layout_above="@id/setter"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    </LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="demo.demo2.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error at following line

```
mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```

--- app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Aprajeeta\Studies\android_work\Demo2\app\src\main\java\demo\demo2\Main3Activity.java:151: error: cannot find symbol tabs

Please check whether id "tabs" not available in your layout. or name is different

Comment: Problem with SlidingTabLayout with Action Bar Class. See this post, it will help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21

Comment: Thank You, but I am unable to find the fix. If you could tell me where exactly am I going wrong and tell me how to correct it

Comment: Will debug online tomorrow or today late evening, If it is OK will char and solve.